# Django : Get (models) __str__ foreignkey (text) value instead of its ID in ajax search result

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, search

I use JS for products search this way :

**models.py (summary)**

```
class Produit(models.Model):
     famille = models.ForeignKey(Famille, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
     sku = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     nom = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     fournisseur = models.ForeignKey(
              Supplier, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=12, null=True)
     qty = models.IntegerField()
     mini = models.IntegerField()
```

[...]

And eg. for Famille, I've set **str** to :

```
class Famille(models.Model):
   nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   [...]

def __str__(self):
    return self.nom
```

In my template I have a search field that is listened by my JS code

**product_search.js**

```
const searchField = document.querySelector("#searchField");
const tableBody = document.querySelector('.table-body');
const appTable = document.querySelector('.app-table');
const tableOutput = document.querySelector('.table-output');
tableOutput.style.display = 'none'

searchField.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
   const searchValue = e.target.value;

   if (searchValue.trim().length > 2) {
       tableBody.innerHTML = '';
       fetch("search-product2", {
           body: JSON.stringify({ searchText: searchValue }),
           method: "POST",
       })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            tableOutput.style.display = 'block'
            appTable.style.display = "none";

            if (data.length === 0) {
                tableOutput.innerHTML = '<h3>Aucun résultat.</h3>';

            } else {
                console.log("data", data);
                data.forEach((item) => {
                    tableBody.innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
                        <th><a href="{% url 'product-update' ${item.id} %}">${item.sku}</a></th>
                        <td>${item.etat_id}</td>
                        <td>${item.nom}</td>
                        <td>${item.famille}</td>
                        <td>${item.mageid}</td>
                        <td>${item.adresse}</td>
                        <td>${item.fournisseur}</td>
                        [...]
                        <td>${item.cau_cli}</td>
                        <td>${item.maxsst2}</td>
                    </tr>
                    `;
                });
            }

          });
  } else {
      console.log('longueur de terme de recherche insuffisante');
      tableOutput.style.display = "none";
      appTable.style.display = "block";
  }
```

});

The JS code calls this

**view.py**

```
def search_product2(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
     search_str = json.loads(request.body).get('searchText')

     products = Produit.objects.filter(sku__icontains=search_str) | 
          Produit.objects.filter(nom__icontains=search_str) | 
          Produit.objects.filter(mageid__icontains=search_str)

     data = products.values()
     return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

My problem is the response contains Foreignkeys ID but not the value set in Models **str** (which is a text value)

I though about rebuilding the querySet response using intermediate queries for retrieving  the needed values but I want to know if another "cleaner" method exists before.

**EDIT :**

Waiting for a better solution in my VIEWS.PY , I iterate on each result and request "text" in DB. I thought it would slow down a lot, but no.

```
if len(data) > 0:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            etat = Etat.objects.get(pk=data[i] 
                  ['etat_id']).etat
            famille = Famille.objects.get(pk=data[i] 
                  ['famille_id']).nom
            fournisseur = Supplier.objects.get(
                pk=data[i]['fournisseur_id']).nom
            data[i]['etat_id'] = etat
            data[i]['famille_id'] = famille
            data[i]['fournisseur_id'] = fournisseur
return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

I know it's not really clean but for the time, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the values of related fields like that:

```
 products = Produit.objects.filter(...)

 data = products.values(
     "etat__etat",
     "nom",
     "famille__nom",
     # your other fields here
 )
       
 return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

If you don't want to have the double underscore keys in your response (like `etat__etat`, you can assign aliases using F expressions:

```
 from django.db.models import F
 ...
 data = products.values(
     "nom",
     nom_d_etat=F("etat__etat"),
     nom_de_famille=F("famille__nom"),
     # your other fields here
 )
```

Note that you can't use an existing field name, i.e. `products.values(etat=F("etat__etat")` would raise the exception:

```
ValueError: The annotation 'etat' conflicts with a field on the model.
```

I would also suggest you use [`.select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in your query:

```
products = Produit.objects.filter(...).select_related("etat", "family")
```

For a completely alternative approach, you can look in [Django REST Framework serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Comment: Excellent ! Presented as you did, it's so simple !
I chose the first solution and handle double underscores in the JS.
And this solution is so lighter than mine.
Thanks
PS : I'll study your 2nd option. Didn't know F either